# GridLayout not not containing generated cards in for loop

Tags: html, css, django

I want to make a gridlayout of cards in html that stores a bunch of cards generated using information I pull from a database. project_photo is an array of image file paths that are referred to generate the cards within the for loop. However, when I run it the gridlayout (named card-grid) only contains the first card that is generated from the for loop. Is there any way to make it so that it contains all the cards generated from the for loop?

```
 <div class="card-grid">
{% for project in context %}
{% with 'jweb/images/'|add:project.image as project_photo %}
    <div class="card">
         <h2 class="card-header" style="text-align:center">{{project.title}}
            <div class="card-image">
              <img  src="{% static project_photo %}" style="float:left">
            </div>
        </h2>  
            
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: where is the `{% endfor %}` ?

Comment: @ilyasbbu just edited